# Asana API - Adding a due_on during task creation

Tags: php, api, curl, asana

I am trying to add a due_on date during task creation with the Asana API and every time it spits out a server 500 error and a random, kinda humorous, message.. Here is an example of the api response when trying to add a task with a due_on or due_at value.

> stdClass Object ( [errors] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object (
>   [message] => Server Error [phrase] => 22 tough cobras kneel kindly ) )
>   )

Is there something going on with these date features? Maybe the 'YYYY-MM-DD' format I'm using (from the api docs) is not correct? When I remove this field I have no problems creating the task, that leaves me to believe the problem is only with the due_on and due_at fields. If i remove line 6 completely it will return a success.

Here is an example of the code that spits out the error:

```
$post_data = array(
    'assignee' => $asana_user_id,
    'notes' => $task_notes,
    'followers[0]' => $asana_user_id,
    'name' => 'Test Task',
    'due_on' => '2015-09-03',
    'workspace' => $workspaceID,
    'projects' => $project_id
);

$curl = curl_init('https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization: Bearer '.$asanaApiToken
));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
$response = curl_exec($curl); // execute post to asana
print_r($response);
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The random and kind of humorous error message you are getting is standard when [server errors occur on the Asana API](https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/errors). It is meant to be a unique string that allows us to track down the exception that caused the 500.

I took a look at what seems to be causing this and I believe it has something to do with parsing the date from the multipart form fields specifically.

If you send the request with a different `Content-Type`, either `application/json` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` then it should be fine.

Here is an example using `application/json`:

```
$curl = curl_init('https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks');

$data_string = json_encode(array(
        "data" => array(
            "workspace" => $workspace,
            "name" => $name,
            "assignee" => "me",
            "due_on" => "2015-09-03")
    )
);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Authorization: Bearer '.$access_token,
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);

$response = curl_exec($curl);

print_r($response);
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thank you for your speedy reply!